# Comparing columns in a multiindex dataframe, creating new df with result

Tags: pandas, dataframe, compare, multi-index

Lets say I have this df:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Sample MultiIndex DataFrame
index = pd.date_range('2023-01-01', '2023-01-05', freq='D')
codes = ['A', 'B', 'C']
columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['MA1', 'MA2', 'MA3', 'MA4', 'MA5'], codes], names=['MA', 'code'])

data = np.random.randint(1, 10, size=(len(index), len(columns)))
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=index, columns=columns)
df
```

The index is datetime and on the multiindex columns, Level 0 is made up of 5 different moving averages (MA1 - MA5) and level 1 is made up of 3 codes (A, B and C). (The real df is far bigger)

Im trying to compare A, B and C's values of MA1 with each of MA2, MA3, MA4 and MA5, and create a new_df.

The new_df will have the same datetime index, and the same level 1 of the multiindex columns (A, B and C), but Level 0 will be different: 'MA1>MA2', 'MA1>MA3', 'MA1>MA4', 'MA1>MA5'.

The new_df will be made up of 1s, -1s and 0s. A 1 if value >, -1 if <, and 0 if same.

So, for each date, the first Level 0 column of new_df ('MA1>MA2') will compare the value of A B and C's MA1 values with their MA2 values, resulting in a 1, -1 or 0.

The second level 0 column of new_df ('MA1>MA3') will compare A, B and c's MA1 values with the MA3 values, etc

Im stuck with invalid index errors, trying to get the right slices to compare... can anyone help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can subtract everything in the dataframe from `MA1`, using [`np.sign`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.sign.html) to generate your desired 1/0/-1 result, and then rename the columns if desired:

```py
out = np.sign(df.loc[:,'MA1'] - df).drop(columns='MA1')
out.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([(f'MA1>{a}',b) for a,b in out.columns], names=out.columns.names)
```

For my sample data of

```
MA         MA1       MA2       MA3       MA4       MA5
code         A  B  C   A  B  C   A  B  C   A  B  C   A  B  C
2023-01-01   5  6  5   4  6  8   7  3  8   9  8  2   3  1  6
2023-01-02   9  7  3   5  3  7   4  9  5   6  8  7   9  3  4
2023-01-03   2  9  4   9  2  5   6  3  4   3  7  3   4  1  8
2023-01-04   7  1  7   9  1  1   6  1  7   1  8  3   2  8  7
2023-01-05   1  6  2   1  8  2   4  9  4   9  9  7   3  1  4
```

This gives:

```
MA         MA1>MA2       MA1>MA3       MA1>MA4       MA1>MA5
code             A  B  C       A  B  C       A  B  C       A  B  C
2023-01-01       1  0 -1      -1  1 -1      -1 -1  1       1  1 -1
2023-01-02       1  1 -1       1 -1 -1       1 -1 -1       0  1 -1
2023-01-03      -1  1 -1      -1  1  0      -1  1  1      -1  1 -1
2023-01-04      -1  0  1       1  0  0       1 -1  1       1 -1  0
2023-01-05       0 -1  0      -1 -1 -1      -1 -1 -1      -1  1 -1
```

Comment: Thats an unexpected way of doing it. Thanks!(FYI... Im on Jupyter with python 3.11 and  out.map gives AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'map'... applymap works fine.

Comment: @AndysPythonStuff just corrected my earlier brain fade; `compare_zero` is of course just `np.sign`, so no need to map at all

Comment: It seems to work, though with the original reply, when I adapted your code to my prog, it said the following:
PerformanceWarning: dropping on a non-lexsorted multi-index without a level parameter may impact performance. 
  out = (df.loc[:,'MA1']-df).drop(columns='MA1')

The new code with 'sign' also gives the same warning:
PerformanceWarning: dropping on a non-lexsorted multi-index without a level parameter may impact performance.
  out = np.sign(df.loc[:,'MA1'] - df).drop(columns='MA1')

Still, thanks a lot for the help, really interesting solution Id never have discovered!

Comment: You should be able to `drop(columns='MA1',level=0)` to resolve that

Comment: That seems to do it! Thanks!